# How to build and run the pub sub tutorial in rosjava?

Tags: ros, tutorial, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

i have a problem to run the pubsub tutorial project in rosjava. I build rosjava_core successfully and followed this tutorial http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html but the step "Executing nodes" doesn't work for me unfortunatelly. The build process (../gradlew installApp) runs without any errors (only a warning "bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6") but there is no path "/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub" in directory build. Even the executable nodes (Talker and Listener) cannot be found anywhere in the project. Maybe the tutorial isn't up to date here?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38731/how-to-build-and-run-the-pub-sub-tutorial-in-rosjava?/) by [ChrisEule](https://answers.ros.org/users/2782/chriseule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also ran into the same problem and think there is an error in the [tutorial](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#executing-nodes).  To execute the example, I had to change:

> ./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker &
> ./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Listener

to:

> ./build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.sjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker &
> ./build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.sjava_tutorial_pubsub.Listener

---

Originally posted by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) with karma: 328 on 2012-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-23**:
What ROS version is used for this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just ran the tutorials, and they worked fine for me. I summarized what I found on a tutorial wiki page.
http://ros.org/wiki/rosjava_core/Tutorials

For me the executable is located in build/install.

Maybe you can paste the contents of your build.gradle as well as the results of

```
$ find src
$ find build
```

here so that it is easier to understand what happened. For now I would suspect that you did not create the folder structure src/main/java as required by gradle.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1